# python filter() function with None as filter argument

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
Input  : list(filter(None,["abs"," ",123,"sdf",""]))

Output : ['abs', ' ', 123, 'sdf']
```

As of my understanding **None** means "**no value**" in python. but in the above case how the filter function is removing the empty string.

I am confused with **None** in python. Can any one explain what exactly **None** represents in the above command and how come it is matching with non-empty strings.

Comment: Are you asking why `""` is filtered out but `" "` is not?

Answer (score 14):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) makes application clear:

> If function is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all
>   elements of iterable that are false are removed.

So `filter(None, it)` removes all Falsy values such as `[]`, `{}`, `0`, `False`, `set()`, `''`, `None`, etc.

Comment: how is this an identify function?

Comment: so, None represents a falsy value and a non empty  string represents true value

Comment: @bonthavijetha, Exactly

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Good spot, *that* bit isn't clear. It seems the docs have defined it *themselves*.

Comment: an identify function normally returns the arguments it is passed, `map()` works like that in Python 2, e.g. `map(None, [0, 1])` > `[0, 1]`, but i don't understand what it means in this context

Comment: @Chris_Rands I know this is old, but looks like no one ever answered your question. The answer here doesn't make it clear that when `function` is `None`, that each item is just returned as is and evaluated as truthy or falsey. In other words, `filter(None, iterable)` is equivalent to `(item for item in iterable if item)`. In other words, the identity function is applied and each item is returned like you show with `map()`. The only difference is that each item is also evaluated in the `if` clause of the generator.